# Woocommerce no actualiza productos después de downgrade

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Desde que hice un downgrade a Woocommerce para volver de la versión 3.0, ya no consigo que aparezca que hay productos en stock aunque no los haya (una opción que las anteriores versiones si tenían). Además, ya no puedo actualizar ciertos productos.

El botón no reacciona. Parecen ser los productos que hay hechos con la versión anterior (3.x), se actualizó la BD al instalar la versión anterior de Woocommerce, pero parece que no funciona del todo bien.

Si alguien puede echarme una mano se lo agradecería :)

Comment: Hola Raúl Gómez, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Lo más importante es haberlo intentado. Sobre tu intento nos contextualizas en los problemas concretos que tienes y sobre ello podemos ayudarte. Si no lo has intentado, investiga y prueba. Después has de [edit] la pregunta para añadir la informacion que falta segun [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Cómo hiciste el downgrade?

Comment: Desactivé el plugin, luego copié el contenido de la carpeta del Woocommerce en su versión 2.6 y la pegué donde se encontraba el plugin actual, luego reactivé el plugin que ya me salía en versión 2.6, al hacerlo me salía la opción de actualizar la BD de Woocommerce, al hacerlo muchos artículos si pueden actualizarse pero otros no.